# What does iCloud Mail sync actually do?

Tags: macos, iphone, ipad, icloud, email

Can someone explain to me please what the 'Mail' feature of iCloud syncing on macOS, iPad, and iPhone etc actually achieves?

[image: iCloud Mail Checkbox macOS]

I have searched online, and some articles from a number of years ago suggest that this syncs an apple @me.com account or similar (which i do not have)..

Obviously, in 2020, pretty much all mail services are online (Gmail, Outlook.com, Yahoo, Office365, Etc.) don't actually **require** 'syncing' via iCloud...

However, it would be nice to change settings for each of these accounts on device #1 (iPad), and perhaps see that reflected on device #2 (iPhone), etc..

The apple site is not actually that helpful in this matter..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Mail button is used to have your Apple mailbox (@icloud.com/@me.com/@mac.com) on your device. If you turn it on your Apple mailbox will just show up in the Mail app.

Note that this option does not synchronize the other mailbox you might have, so in your case it will not be useful. You can find more informations about it [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/icloud/mmdd8d1d47/icloud).

Comment: so it will do precisely nothing for me as I don’t have an @icloud.com/@me.com/@mac.com account?

Comment: No, If I recall they will ask you if you want to create a @icloud.com mail on iOS, I have no idea for MacOS

Comment: interesting - well i totally don't want that hassle, i'll leave it unchecked. seems a bit pointless!